# Spring AMQP exception handling basics

Tags: spring, amqp, spring-amqp

I have a Listener class (that implements Spring's `MessageListener` interface) where I need to not requeue any messages if an exception occurs, but I want to post the message to a different queue.

It seems like I need the Listener to catch an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`, but I've read that I need it to throw the exception instead. If I do that, I can't re-post the message.

Should I just catch a plain Exception and do the re-post there? Is there any need to actually throw the `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` at that point?

I'm wondering about the best practice for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways to achieve this.

Most simply, you just need to catch all the exception on the client side and throw a `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`.

Otherwise, have a look at `FatalExceptionStrategy`, you need have your own strategy and let it always return `true`

Comment: Thanks.  What would happen if I don't throw the AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException exception at that point? It gets requeued? I don't have any AdviceChain in my config with a retryInterceptor. Should I just utilize a dead letter queue?

Comment: @mstrom if you are not ready to handle the exceptions, why do you need a DLQ, just override the strategy or add or surround your `handleMessage` method with try catch block, this will do the trick

Comment: If you handle the exception by publishing then just consume the message - no exception means the message is acked. The only real reason for throwing that exception is if you are using a DLX/DLQ. You can also configure a retry interceptor with a `RepublishMessageRecoverer` which will publish the failed message to another queue together with headers containing information such as the stack trace. You can also set `defaultRequeueRejected` to false, to always reject failed messages regardless of the exception.