# Reprocess failed RabbitMQ messages manually

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a dead-letter queue which stores failed messages. Is there have a way to manually trigger a listener to process the messages in the dead-letter queue? I’m using Spring AMQP.

Comment: in this case you shouldnot put is in DLX, but in db, in case retry retrieve it from db and resend the msg again

Comment: I'm not aware of your usecase, but there are lots of possibility.. i can post you one. just gimme a min.

Comment: Thanks. And is there Spring AMQP "hook" where I define if any exception was thrown during processing, then call this method which will store the necessary data in the db?

Comment: this is another question, aber for sure, there are different mechanism to do this, you can checkout `FatalExceptionStrategy` etc.. like i said.. it depends..

Comment: You can trigger a listener, like i said, you should decide it by your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said, it depends on your use case, but I can assume you are looking for something from spring amqp out-of-the-box.

just have a look at [BlockingQueueConsumer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/BlockingQueueConsumer.html), you can i.e. prefetch one message if you want, then start it manually.

Please be aware that you need choose solution according to your case, maybe you just need a flag in db to mark the job is failed, or save the msg in db.

Comment: @Glide checkout another answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245473/spring-amqp-exception-handling-basics

Comment: @Glide You have a DLX, make the DLX save msg to DB, solves your problem, if save-to-db is the solution

Comment: From your answer, I like the ```FatalExceptionStrategy``` approach but that's not mentioned in the Spring AMQP doc. How do I define that or a general ErrorHandler?

Comment: Sorry, nevermind about `ErrorHandler`. Figured I can set it via `SimpleMessageListenerContainer.setErrorHandler()`. The Spring AMQP doc is lacking.